# Repetition of nested IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, lookup, worksheet-function

I'm struggling to get an Excel query to work. I'm trying to have multiple queries like this within a query and am not sure how to work it. The query so far is this:

```
     =IF(B6=$R$2,B2*$S$2,IF($B$6=$R$3,B2*$S$3,IF(B6=$R$4,B2*$S$4,B2)))
```

Here is what I'm trying to do, there are the 7 multipliers below, the above statement is for only one of them.

[image]

The logic is, that if the cell says `Good` it is multiplied by 97.5%, if `Bad` by 102.5%, if `OK` it's multiplied by 100%, but I need the odds to be multiplied by all 7 areas beneath. So its essentially an if/else statement 7 times within itself:

If B6 = `Good` * S2, else * S4, then if B7 = `Good` * S2, else S4, essentially that repeated 7 times down.

How can I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

In B2 and copied down:

```
=B2*LOOKUP(B6,{"Bad","Good","OK"},{1.025,0.975,1})
```

might suit but would still require entries into E2 etc.

Might not be as easy to understand but should give the same results (for the three conditions) and is a little shorter:

```
=B2*(1+.025*((B6="Bad")-(B6="Good")))
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use VLOOKUP as follows :

```
   =B2 * VLOOKUP(B6,$R$2:$S$4,2) * VLOOKUP(B7,$R$2:$S$4,2) * 
         VLOOKUP(B8,$R$2:$S$4,2) * VLOOKUP(B9,$R$2:$S$4,2) * 
         VLOOKUP(B10,$R$2:$S$4,2) * VLOOKUP(B11,$R$2:$S$4,2) * 
         VLOOKUP(B12,$R$2:$S$4,2)
```

You could develop a simple User Defined function through VBA though. It would be better and more efficient.

Comment: oh yes yes sorry. I am using the french system.

Comment: I might have to look into the vba, thanks for the help!

Comment: When I add Bad in it goes to #N/A

Comment: Oh yes, you should add a 0 as the forth argument (which is FALSE, as to get the exact result) 
So the formula would be :
       `=B2 * VLOOKUP(B6,$R$2:$S$4,2,0) * VLOOKUP(B7,$R$2:$S$4,2,0) * 
         VLOOKUP(B8,$R$2:$S$4,2,0) * VLOOKUP(B9,$R$2:$S$4,2,0) * 
         VLOOKUP(B10,$R$2:$S$4,2,0) * VLOOKUP(B11,$R$2:$S$4,2,0) * 
         VLOOKUP(B12,$R$2:$S$4,2,0)`